# iframe with pointer-events: none; but with a div inside it that has pointer-events: auto;

Tags: html, events, iframe, pointer-events

It is possible to have an outer div with pointer-events: none; and another div inside it with pointer-events: auto;. The outer div will be transparent to click events (ie it won't react to click events but underlying html controls will) and the inner one will.

However, I now have a scenario where I need to do the same thing with an iframe, but it is not working. I set pointer-events: none; on the iframe, but then the inner divs that should be clickable are not even if they have pointer-events: auto; set.

[There is another similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329991/make-an-iframe-have-pointer-events-none-but-not-on-a-div-inside-that), but is has been closed for being off-topic. I don't understand why. It is a very valid html/css question.

Comment: @PhistucK Even if I have control over the containing window and the iframe itself?

Answer (score 3):

iFrames are treated as a single piece of content and not part of the page in which the iFrame resides, so, no, it is not possible.

The renderer and DOM are treating the iFrame as a black box. This is exactly why you cannot, for example, run regular methods like `iFrameElement.childNodes[0]` and similar (and get the `<html>` of the iFrame). You have to run `iFrameElement.contentWindow.document.documentElement` or something like that. It is a completely separate browsing context.