# Make an item clickable in an iframe with style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that looks something like this:

```
<IFRAME style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"  SRC="####" WIDTH=320 HEIGHT=50 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 SCROLLING=no BORDERCOLOR='#000000'>...</IFRAME>
```

Inside the iFrame I have an element that looks like this:

```
<div id="trigger-container-80791" style="position: static !important;">...<div>
```

Nothing inside this iframe is clickable because of `style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"` Is there any way to have the  override this style and be 'clickable' by adding some kind of Javascript in the IFRAME? I cannot modify the attributes in the IFRAME.

Comment: You might be able to target the element in the iframe's `contentDocument` and set `pointer-events: all`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to have the override this style and be 'clickable' by
>   adding some kind of Javascript in the IFRAME?

No. The pointer-events:none will prevent any mouse events (click, mousedown, etc) from reaching your iframe, so there will be nothing to hang your javascript on.

See also [iframe with pointer-events: none; but with a div inside it that has pointer-events: auto;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499688/iframe-with-pointer-events-none-but-with-a-div-inside-it-that-has-pointer-even)